# How to group $f(x)$s in terms of asymptotic behavior?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

> Consider the folowing subsets of possible $f(x)$s:
>
> - **Group 1:** There exists a constant $c<1$ such that $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(e^{c x})$.
> - **Group 2:** If for all $c<1$, $f(x)=\omega(e^{c x})$.
>
> Is there a simpler way of grouping them in terms of asymptotic notations such as of Big-O, little-o, etc.?

This is a part of a bigger problem. To solve the problem I had two solutions, each one for one of the groups. The grouping I have above is a little strange, but that's what I could come up with. Is there a simpler grouping? I thought it might be equivalent to:

- **Group 1:** $f(x)=o(e^{c x})$.
- **Group 2:** $f(x)=\Omega(e^{c x})$.

Then, I realized it is not correct. Any suggestions for a simpler notation for such a grouping?

Comment: You can always invent a notation. Or you could say $\log(f(x)) \in O(x)$ or something like that

Comment: @darkmalthrop Thanks. Did you notice $c<1$?

Comment: Oh oops yeah I missed that

Comment: You could say something like $f(\log(x)) \in O(x^c)$